# What do you think about the sentence, "Quality does not compromise?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> “Quality does not compromise.”

Do you think the sentence is natural? Even if it is grammatically correct, I think *quality* is something that "is compromised", since it doesn't have any power on its own to "compromise".

Back to the question. Do you think it's grammatically correct and natural? If not, how would you change the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of slogan made by advertising people.  **Quality** is personified, treated as if it could make judgments.  It is natural enough in the sense that native speakers (at least those in the US) encounter such statements all the time if they are not living in the middle of the desert with no access to radio or TV or internet or print media.

People understand it to mean that a company interested in making products of high quality will not compromise in ways that would lower the quality, such as by using lesser materials, or allowing sloppier engineering tolerances, or employing inadequate quality control measures.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is completely *natural*, and (to some extent) rather elegant.  Whether it is also *meaningful* is open to debate.

As with any language, English is rich in figurative expressions, including metaphor.  In this case "quality" is a *personification* of a larger concept, something like:

> **people** whose intention is to produce good quality

or

> the **desire** to produce good quality.

These kind of expressions are fairly common.  Here are a few more related to quality:

> "Quality means doing it right when no one is looking" - Henry Ford
>
> "Quality is the difference between style and fashion - Giorgio Armani
>
> "Quality is not an act; it is a habit" - Aristotle